# $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{(-1/2)((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2} dx = 1$, no polar coordinates

Tags: integration, statistics, normal-distribution

I want to show using the integral below that the area under a normal curve is equal to 1.
How can I show that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{(-1/2)((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2} dx = 1$$ *without* polar coordinates, double integrals, or other formulas? Is there a way to only use $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(-1/2)x^2} dx = \sqrt{2\pi}$$ and $z = (x-\mu)/\sigma$ without any other functions or variables?

Comment: Do you want to show the first one from scratch or by assuming the second one? The latter is much easier, as it is a simple $u$-substitution.

Comment: I want to show it by assuming the second. Could you explain a bit more on how you would use u-substitution?

Comment: The scary look of the integrand is simply a disguise. Write $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ so that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1$$ by the second identity. Then substituting $x=(u-\mu)/\sigma$, we have $\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}u/\sigma$, hence $$1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(\frac{u-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sigma}.$$ Simplifying the integrand of the last integral gives the first identity.

Comment: I see, thank you! Out of curiosity, if I wanted to show that the second integral = $\sqrt{2\pi}$ without polar coordinates or gamma functions, would there be a similar process?